# Concatenating two variables with an underscore

Tags: php

I want the output to be concatenating the two variables I have.
The `$out [1]` is now echo: `/home/data/main/folders/folder1/size1`

The `$arr[$folder_name] [1]` is `echo folder1`

I want the echo for `$newfoldername` to be `/home/data/main/folders/folder1/size1_folder1`

```
$newfoldername = $out [1] . '_'  $arr[$folder_name];
echo $out [1] ;
echo $arr[$folder_name] [1] ;
rename ( $out [1] ,  $newfoldername  ) ;
```

Comment: There is no question or problem statement here

Comment: I think the syntaxt for _ is wrong for this: $newfoldername = $out [1] . '_'  $arr[$folder_name]; is With the code above /home/data/main/folders/folder1/size1/folder1

Comment: *Why* do you think it is wrong? What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: I want it to be /home/data/main/folders/folder1/size1_folder1 not /home/data/main/folders/folder1/size1/folder1

Comment: @morimba try editing and clarifying your question.  With your inputs, what you've tried,  and your desired output.

Comment: Since you've fixed the syntax error, you maybe want to `echo $newfoldername;` instead of `echo $out[1];`

Comment: looks like the code is ok.  But the should hade the $out[1] to be witout the / at the end

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand the question, 
but you have mistake in this string

`$newfoldername = $out [1] . '_'  $arr[$folder_name];`

take this code. it is whithout mistakes;

```
$newfoldername = $out [1] . '_' .  $arr[$folder_name];
```

Answer (score 0):

For short you can just:

```
rename ($out[1], $out[1].'_'.$arr[$folder_name] );
```

Or echo that:

```
echo $out[1].'_'.$arr[$folder_name];
```

Careful with syntax when sharing problems, it might be the source of the problem. But your IDE should have showed you.

Answer (score 0):

This was the correct solution for me:

```
$newfoldername = substr( $out [1], 0, -1 )  .  "_"  .  $arr[$folder_name];
```